# React Leaflet Bound not working as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm using [react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) package to create bound animation on the map from selected markers as seen on the screenshot below.

[image]

Here is the full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-marker-with-bound-869mj

The map will be bound if only the selected markers change.

I try to implement the bound animation sample code from the documentation here https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-view-bounds/

As we can see from the screenshot above, the map, the markers, the rectangle, and the panel (top-right corner) are displaying and working fine.

But if we change the selected markers (through the panel), the bound animation is not working properly (not showing all of the markers).

And if we empty the selected markers (no marker is selected in the panel), the app crashes and produces an **error** `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')`.

So, **my questions** are:

1. how could this happen?
2. what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I could do it after directly updating the newest value of bounds (location list) inside `onCheckboxChange` function.
So the `useEffect` hook with `selectedPlaces` is not needed anymore.

```js
const onCheckboxChange = (inputIndex) => {
  let newPlaces = [...selectedPlaces];
  newPlaces[inputIndex].selected = !newPlaces[inputIndex].selected;
  setSelectedPlaces(newPlaces);

  let newBounds = selectedPlaces.filter((item) => item.selected);
  newBounds = newBounds.map((item) => item.location);
  setBounds(newBounds);
  map.fitBounds(newBounds);
};

useEffect(() => {
  map.fitBounds(initialBounds);
}, []);
```

Here is the working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/learn-react-leaflet-cnk8tm

Answer (score 2):

The error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'lat')` is because you are passing an empty array of markers to `<Rectangle>`. You need at least two markers to define a rectangles corners so check that you have at least two:

```
{/* RECTANGLE */}
{markerList && markerList.length >= 2 && (
  <Rectangle bounds={markerList} pathOptions={{ color: "red" }} />
)}
```

Comment: thanks, I appreciate your answer but still produces `Bounds are not valid` error. actually, I've found another way to use bounds animation using `@react-google-maps/api` package